# What are the challenges to consider while automating Desktop client application that has WPF framework?

Tags: automated-testing, desktop-application

I want to automate regression testing for a desktop client application. The application uses WPF as UI framework.

I have just started to investigate various tools. I am keen to know what are the challenges observed while automating a desktop application that uses WPF.

Comment: Sim, please try to narrow your question to a specific problem - your question is too broad and opinion-based.
What is your context, what are your goals, and what have you done so far?

Comment: Hello,I am just keen to understand challenges observed while planning to automate a desktop application based on user experience in real life.

Comment: I would assume that you understand that "a desktop application" is a very broad term. It can be a CLI-based software, video editor, a distributive computation simulator, a web browser, etc. And the list is infinite. Considering that, basically any answer can be considered as acceptable or not acceptable, regardless of its length. I would suggest you to disclosure on a high level your context, so contributors can focus on sharing their experience in a similar situation.

Comment: Hi, appreciate your feedback. if I say the desktop client application is created using Windows presentation Foundation(WPF) (UI framework), will that be more clear in context? Please advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Sikuli. It is an image based automation tool. It will search for screenshots you previously provided and do certain actions that you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Appium has window driver. So you can use it.
But What I was annoyed was finding elements.
It's hard to catch element.
Windows has "inspecter" program which supports to find elements.
The elements should have names or id values.
If your developers help to write automation code, ask them to assign id or names to each element.

Another choice is using Image based automation. There are some tools, but I've used "sikuli". It's really easy to learn and write code. But managing Image variables is maintaining issue.

Comment: Is Sikuli an opensource tool?

Comment: Yes it is. http://sikulix.com/